# URL open inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a URL inside a modal dialog.. I thought this would be quite simple but seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.. Can anyone see why this isnt working? The dialog is opening, but the webpage isnt appearing inside.. Thanks for any help :D

```
<a  href='http://www.google.co.uk' class='ls-modal'>Login</a>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Event</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    //JS script
    $('.ls-modal').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

Comment: CORS issue ....

Comment: do you know how this can be fixed?